# How to direct command from console shell script (ssh) to xserver

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I am trying to obtain a value from the xserver running on a raspberry pi. The command `DISPLAY=:0 xssstate -i` works at the command line but not when running the script.

running the script localy works perfectly, but when running it over ssh it doesnt

Script:

```
enter code here

#!/bin/bash

# Wanted trigger timeout in milliseconds.
IDLE_TIME=$((10*1000))

triggered=0

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
sleep 1
sstime=$(DISPLAY=:0 xssstate -i)
echo "idletime $IDLE_TIME"
echo "sstime $sstime"
if [ "$sstime" -gt "$IDLE_TIME" ] || [ "$triggered" -eq 0 ]
then
        echo 235 > /sys/waveshare/rpi_backlight/brightness
        triggered=1
elif [ "$sstime" -lt "$IDLE_TIME" ] || [ "$triggered" -eq 1 ]
then
        echo 0 > /sys/waveshare/rpi_backlight/brightness
        triggered=0
else
        triggered=0
fi

done
```

Output:

```
No protocol specified
Cannot open display.
idletime 10000
sstime
./backLTctrl.sh: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
No protocol specified
Cannot open display.
idletime 10000
sstime
./backLTctrl.sh: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
./backLTctrl.sh: line 19: [: : integer expression expected
No protocol specified
Cannot open display.
idletime 10000
sstime
./backLTctrl.sh: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
No protocol specified
Cannot open display.
idletime 10000
sstime
./backLTctrl.sh: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
./backLTctrl.sh: line 19: [: : integer expression expected
```

Comment: You mentioned ssh in the title, but nowhere else. How exactly is SSH involved? Is it really?

Comment: running the script localy works perfectly, but when running it over ssh it doesnt

Comment: `ssh -X` or maybe set xauth another way

Comment: "running the script localy works perfectly, but when running it over ssh it doesnt" – This is something you should state explicitly in the question body. How *exactly* do you run the script "over ssh"? Please [edit] the question and add information there. Be specific.